# Finding shortest distance to object based on mouse click in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am having problems getting this function to work properly. I have to create a winform app that acts as a taxi mapper. On load the taxis are placed in the same location based on a text file. When a user clicks on the form the nearest taxi is supposed to move to the "user" or location, then stop.

Everything is working fine except that the closest taxi does not always go to the location. A taxi further away will go to the location instead. It seems to work some of the time, but not all the time. I am not sure if my logic is correct in the `Form1_MouseDown` function

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (pickUp) //Are we picking up a passenger?
    {
        //Convert mouse pointer location to local window locations
        int mLocalX = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X;
        int mLocalY = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y;

        //set the minimum value (for range finding)
        int min = int.MaxValue;
        //Temporary object to get the handle for the taxi object we want to manipulate
        taxiCabTmp = new TaxiClass();

        //Iterate through each object to determine who is the closest
        foreach (TaxiClass taxiCab in taxi)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(Math.Abs(taxiCab.CabLocationX - mLocalX) + Math.Abs(taxiCab.CabLocationY - mLocalY)) <= min)
            {
                min = Math.Abs(Math.Abs(taxiCab.CabLocationX - mLocalX) + Math.Abs(taxiCab.CabLocationY - mLocalY));
                //We found a minimum, grab a handle to the object's instance
                taxiCab.GetReference(ref taxiCabTmp);
            }
        }
        //Call the propogate method so it can spin off a thread to slowly change it's location for the timer to also change
        taxiCabTmp.Propogate(mLocalX - 20, mLocalY - 20);
        taxiCabTmp.occupied = true; //This taxi object is occupied
        pickUp = false; //We are not picking up a passenger at the moment
    }
    else //We are dropping off a passenger
    {
        taxiCabTmp.Propogate(this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X, this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y);
        taxiCabTmp.occupied = false;
        pickUp = true; //We can pick up a passenger again!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula to calculate distance between two coordinates.

```
var distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(taxiCab.CabLocationX - mLocalX, 2) + Math.Pow(taxiCab.CabLocationY - mLocalY, 2));
if (distance <= min) {
    min = distance;
    //We found a minimum, grab a handle to the object's instance
    taxiCab.GetReference(ref taxiCabTmp);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the calculation you use for determining distance will not always be correct. Objects at an angle will calculate to be further away than they really are.

Have a look at this link for more information: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm

Here's an example:

```
int mLocalX = 1;
int mLocalY = 1;
int taxiCab.CabLocationX = 2;
int taxiCab.CabLocationY = 2;

double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((taxiCab.CabLocationX - mLocalX), 2) + Math.Pow((taxiCab.CabLocationY - mLocalY), 2));
```

Just as a side note, you shouldn't append your classes with Class, i.e TaxiClass, it should simply be called Taxi.